# SimpleHTTPServer "server forever" blocking rest of script

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

Below is my script.  It creates a directory, detects an arduino device, continuously writes output from it to a text file, and serves that file in a local server.  From what I can tell (and have read), this line:

```
httpd.serve_forever()
```

causes nothing after to be processed.  The text file never get's written to.  If I move httpd.serve_forever() line down further, it'll process everything up to that point, so this does appear to reaffirm this theory.  How can I do what I need?  Is it clear where I'm going wrong?

```
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import os
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import sys,os

fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))

try:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(fileDir, 'log'))
except OSError:
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(fileDir, 'log')):
        raise

directory = os.path.join(fileDir, 'log')
log = os.path.join(directory, 'log.txt')
os.chdir(directory)

PORT = 8080
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()

def get_ports():

    ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

    return ports

def findArduino(portsFound):

    commPort = 'None'
    numConnection = len(portsFound)

    for i in range(0,numConnection):
        port = foundPorts[i]
        strPort = str(port)

        if 'Arduino' in strPort:
            splitPort = strPort.split(' ')
            commPort = (splitPort[0])

    return commPort

foundPorts = get_ports()        
connectPort = findArduino(foundPorts)

if connectPort != 'None':
    ser = serial.Serial(connectPort,baudrate = 9600, timeout=1)
    while 1:
        if ser.inWaiting():
            with open(log, "w") as txtfile:
                x=ser.readline()
                txtfile.write(x)
                txtfile.flush()
                if x=="\n":
                    txtfile.seek(0)
                    txtfile.truncate
                    txtfile.flush()
    ser.close()

else:
   print('Connection Issue!')

print('DONE')
```

Comment: `serve_forever`, as many suggest, is implemented using infinite loop (until shutdown).

Comment: So, how might I remedy this?  How can I continuously serve the file while continuously writing to it?

Comment: Run `serve_forever` using thread.